# why b-modal is not invoked when created in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I wanted to invoke the b-modal whenever the component is created but its not happening. Yet on clicking the button, the modal is invoked. How can we fix this?

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <button @click="$bvModal.show('modal1')">Show</button>
    <b-modal id="modal1" title="Loading" hide-footer no-close-on-backdrop>
      <p>Preparing the Application, Please wait</p>
    </b-modal>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  created() {
    this.showModal();
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.$bvModal.show("modal1");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but our comments here disappeared. Anyway, if you feel that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393717/1814420) helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to interact with the HTML element, it's better to use the `mounted` hook.

According to the [Vue Lifecycle diagram](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#lifecycle-diagram) and the [API documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted), in the `mounted` hook, the elements are already rendered (not guarantee for child elements), so that you can interact with them.

Meanwhile, in the `created` hook, you have access only to the data.

[image: Vue Lifecycle]

In short, in your case, the `mounted` hook is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mounted` hook instead of `created`.

By the time `created` hook is called, the component has no template yet, so all the child-component are not instanciated yet. You only have access to props and initial data.
Thus is won't do anything.

In `mounted`, you are sure everything is instanciated, included the `b-modal` component. So calling `$bvModal.show()` should work :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <button @click="$refs.modal1.show()">Show</button>
    <b-modal ref=modal1 id="modal1" title="Loading" hide-footer no-close-on-backdrop>
      <p>Preparing the Application, Please wait</p>
    </b-modal>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.modal1.show();
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please also tell what how did you fix the problem

Comment: In the created the modal is not yet created. But in the mounted it is, so you just have to launch it only at that moment